# Enable users to change change and add taxonomies of posts

Tags: plugins, taxonomy, users, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I would like to enable users to add tags/categories, and to vote for tags/catergories for each post

It would be a simple voting system : each user can vote for each tags (+1 / -1) and only tags that have a +1/-1 ratio of 75% would be confirmed and used as tags for the post

Do you know how to do it on wordpress ? Is it even possible ? Or is there a plugin that can do it ?